# cmd.exe process never completes

Tags: c#, .net, console

I have the following code.

```
ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
si.RedirectStandardInput = true;
si.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
si.UseShellExecute = false;
si.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
si.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process p = Process.Start(si);
p.StandardInput.Write("ipconfig");
p.StandardInput.Write("exit");
string consoleOutput = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string dir="here";
```

The execution reaches "string consoleOutput" but never reaches "string dir" ie the code gets stuck on reading the StandardOutput. It is runnung from within a console application if this makes any difference.

Comment: If you're running from a console application already, why aren't you just invoking `ipconfig` on it's own rather than spawning `cmd` unnecessarily?

Comment: can I do this with console.write?

Comment: console.write would not actually launch the process, it's the `Process.Start(si)` that launches it.

Comment: I was asking from a point of view of executing the commands from within the same process as the running console application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly finish writing to the standard input by closing the stream. See [Microsoft's example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx).

In summary:

```
        p.StandardInput.Write("exit");
        p.StandardInput.Close(); // <-- You need this
        string consoleOutput = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Edit: Tested in Visual Studio.

**By the way**, you want to use `WriteLine()` instead of `Write()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WriteLine` instead of `Write` to write a string with a final newline. (You might have to call `Flush()` as well, but I'm not sure). It won't hurt to `Close` the stream, as another answer says.

And yes, you don't need `cmd.exe`, you can start `ipconfig` directly (as advised by @Petesh in a comment).

Comment: `Flush()` and `FlushAsync()` don't seem to do it for some reason. Not sure why.